# Make an array from multiple arrays with common objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json which is an array with 2 nested arrays:

```
[
  [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Laughing",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Megaphone",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Yawning",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ]
]
```

I need to make a new array of the **common object names** seen in both arrays like this:

```
[{
            "name": "WalkBack"
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront"
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft"
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight"
          }]
```

So in this case the walk animations are the common names. I tried using:

```
result = firstArray.filter(o => secondArray.some(({name}) => o.name === name));
```

but this only works if you know have names for the inner arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: I answered but please tell me if I understood your problem correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to use the `reduce` method on them by taking first array as a reference. Something like this:

```js
const data=[[{name:"WalkBack",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkFront",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkLeft",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkRight",frameRate:15},{name:"Laughing",frameRate:15},{name:"Megaphone",frameRate:15},{name:"Yawning",frameRate:15}],[{name:"WalkBack",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkFront",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkLeft",frameRate:15},{name:"WalkRight",frameRate:15}]];

const [refArr, ...rest] = data

const formattedData = refArr.reduce((commons = [], item) => {
  let isCommon = rest.every(arr => arr.some(itemInArr => item.name === itemInArr.name))
  return isCommon ? [...commons, item] : commons
}, [])

console.log(formattedData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's still including the uncommon object names such as "Laughing" and "Megaphone".

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my answer. It will work on any size of an array.

Comment: Thanks, would this still work if there are more than 2 inner arrays?

Comment: It is also cross-browser compatible since it uses only `reduce`, `some`, and `every` prototype methods. If you try to use `flat` to flatten them first and then process it, it would break in IE (unless you are poly filling). But, I would rather prefer what is available than adding more code to the bundle. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you can flat your data then you `reduce` it and `filter` out records by checking length, if it has more than one value.

```js
var data=[ [ { "name": "WalkBack", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkFront", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkLeft", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkRight", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "Laughing", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "Megaphone", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "Yawning", "frameRate": 15 } ], [ { "name": "WalkBack", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkFront", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkLeft", "frameRate": 15 }, { "name": "WalkRight", "frameRate": 15 } ]];

var result2 =  Object.entries(data.flat().reduce((acc, {name})=>{
   acc[name] = [...(acc[name] || []),{name}];
   return acc;
},{})).filter(([k,v])=>v.length>1).map(([name])=>({name}));

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is somewhat hard-coded to know that there are always 2 arrays. It could be 2 or more. Anyway to automate it more?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward, I have edited my answer let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks I'm just having trouble using .flat(). I'm just trying to get my typescript to allow it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, there's no way I would have guessed all that :)

Answer (score 0):

First you gather all the "names", then you filter the duplicates :)

```js
var arrays = [
  [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Laughing",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Megaphone",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Yawning",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ]
]

var names = []
arrays.forEach(function(array) {
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    names.push(item.name)
  })
})

var result = []
names.filter( (x,i,a) => a.slice(0,i).find(y=>y==x)  ).forEach(x=>result.push({name: x}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
  [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Laughing",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Megaphone",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Yawning",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "name": "WalkBack",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkFront",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "WalkLeft",
            "frameRate": 15
          },
            {
            "name": "WalkRight",
            "frameRate": 15
          }
        ]
];
debugger;
var arr1 = arr[0], arr2 = arr[1],
myObj = {};
arr1.forEach(i=>{
 if(!myObj[i.name]){
   myObj[i.name] = true;
 }
}
);

arr2.forEach(i=>{
 if(!myObj[i.name]){
   delete myObj[i.name]
 }
})

console.log(myObj)
```